# Self-defined simple linked list class feedback

Tags: c++, linked-list

I want to implement a Simple Linked List class that works with any data type so I'm using template. I also need to implement a Iterator class that will work with my list. This has proven to be a bigger challenge than I thought would be.
So I started working:

```
template<typename Element>
class Node;

template<typename Element>
class SimpleLinkedList;

template<typename Element>
class Iterator;

template<typename Element>
class Node
{
private:
    Element data;
    Node<Element> *next;

public:
    // constructor
    Node();

    // destructor
    ~Node();

    // getters
    Element getData();

    Node<Element> *getNext();

    // setters
    void setData(Element newData);

    void setNext(Node<Element> *adr);

    // has next
    bool hasNext();
};

template<typename Element>
class SimpleLinkedList
{
    friend class Node<Element>;

private:
    Node<Element> *head;

public:
    // constructor
    SimpleLinkedList();

    // destructor
    ~SimpleLinkedList();

    // getters
    Node<Element> *getHead();

    Node<Element> *getNode();

    // add
    void append(Element newData);

    // is list
    bool valid();
};

template<typename Element>
class Iterator
{
    friend class SimpleLinkedList<Element>;
    friend class Node<Element>;

private:
    Node<Element> *it;

public:
    // constructor
    Iterator();

    // constructor with params
    Iterator(Node<Element> *head);

    // destructor
    ~Iterator();

    // has next
    bool valid();

    // step
    Node<Element> *step();

    // ++ operatpr
    Iterator<Element>* & operator++();
};

/*
 * Node implementation
 */

// constructor
template<typename Element>
Node<Element>::Node()
{
    this->data = Element(); // default constructor for Element
    this->next = 0;
}

// destructor
template<typename Element>
Node<Element>::~Node()
{
    // not sure
    // note to self: test this!
}

// getters
template<typename Element>
Element Node<Element>::getData()
{
    return this->data;
}

template<typename Element>
Node<Element> Node<Element>::*getNext()
{
    return this->next;
}

// setters
template<typename Element>
void Node<Element>::setData(Element newData)
{
    this->data = newData;
}

template<typename Element>
void Node<Element>::setNext(Node<Element> *adr)
{
    this->next = adr;
}

/*
 * return value:
 *      true - it's not the last node
 *      false - it's the last node
 */
template<typename Element>
bool Node<Element>::hasNext()
{
    if(this->next != 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

/*
 * SimpleLinkedList implementation
 */

// constructor
template<typename Element>
SimpleLinkedList<Element>::SimpleLinkedList()
{
    this->head = Node<Element>();
}

// destructor
template<typename Element>
SimpleLinkedList<Element>::~SimpleLinkedList()
{
    //
}

// getters
template<typename Element>
Node<Element> *SimpleLinkedList<Element>::getHead()
{
    return this->head;
}

template<typename Element>
Node<Element> *SimpleLinkedList<Element>::getNode()
{
    return this; // not sure how to do this
}

// add new
template<typename Element>
void SimpleLinkedList<Element>::append(Element newData)
{
    Node<Element> *newNode = Node<Element>();
    newNode->setData(newData);
    Node<Element> *temp = Node<Element>();
    temp = this->head;
    while(temp->next != 0) // while not last element
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    newNode->next = 0;
    temp->next = newNode;
}


template<typename Element>
bool SimpleLinkedList<Element>::valid()
{
    if(this->head != 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

/*
 * Iterator implementation
 */

// constructor
template<typename Element>
Iterator<Element>::Iterator()
{
    this->it = 0;
}

/*
 * recieves the first element of a SimpleLinkedList
 */
template<typename Element>
Iterator<Element>::Iterator(Node<Element> *head)
{
    this->it = head;
}

// destructor
template<typename Element>
Iterator<Element>::~Iterator()
{
}

/*
 * return value:
 *      true - valid list entru
 *      false - outside of lists bounds
 */
template<typename Element>
bool Iterator<Element>::valid()
{
    if(this->it != 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

// gets the next list entry
template<typename Element>
Node<Element> *Iterator<Element>::step()
{
    return this->it->next;
}

// it++ operatpr
//template<typename Element>
//Iterator<Element>::Iterator<Element> & operator++()
//{
    // research more about this
//}
```

I think I have a major problem with this: 
I can declare a new Node, let's say:

```
Node<int> *newNode;
```

But I can't say

```
Node<int> *newNode = Node<int>();
```

This only works when newNode is not a pointer, but my Linked List will not work if the nodes are not pointers. Major flaw. 
What is the correct approach of this problem?

Comment: You need to call `new` to allocate a new `Node` dynamically. Also, trying to use encapsulation in the `Node` is severe overkill, just use a dumb `struct` and put all logic into `SimpleLinkedList` itself.

Comment: Severe overkill or not that's what my assignment says. I'll try it, if I start to slowly loose my soul while I do this I'll just go with a struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you can allocate variables in three different memory areas:

**Stack:**

```
void func()
{
    Node<int>  node();          // An instance of type 'Node<int>'
    Node<int>* nodePtr = &node; // A pointer to the instance above
    ...
}
```

**Data-Section:**

```
Node<int>  node();          // An instance of type 'Node<int>'
Node<int>* nodePtr = &node; // A pointer to the instance above
...
```

**Heap:**

```
Node<int>* nodePtr = new Node<int>();
// A pointer to an instance of type 'Node<int>'
```

You need to allocate your `Node<int>` instance in the heap, and then use a pointer to that instance, as in the example above. Please notice that the pointer itself is **not** in the heap (it's in the stack if used as a local variable, or in the data-section if used as a global variable).

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
Node<int> *newNode = new Node<int>();
                     ^^^---- new!
```